# Highcharts graph zoom on react native

Tags: react-native, highcharts, react-highcharts

I used Highcharts on my project in mobile react native and found after trying to pinch-to-zoom on graph x-axis and y-axis are not refreshing to shows smaller x-coordinate numbers.
However when I used to work in Expo, it was properly worked and showing correct number during pinch-to-zoom.

Please advise if you ran into same issue and how you fixed it? I am guessing there should be an event needs to be trigger to refresh charts.

[image]

[image]

Tried to use Highcharts zoon feature on react native code for my graph, expecting to see smaller numbers of X and Y axis on graph after pinch-to -zoom

Answer (score -1):

I have found, that you have already asked your question on Freshdesk, our support channel. In the future, please do not duplicate topics across our support channels, as we work as a single team of developers.

The React-Native package is deprecated, so that means, that we dropped support for that package, and it now is in hands of the community. If you need any support with this package, you can create an Issue in GitHub and might find some help there. Alternatively, you can try to search for some new package, which is not official. On the other hand, you can try to use methods, like `chart.redraw` (https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#redraw) or `chart.reflow` (https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#reflow) - they are responsible for redrawing/reflowing the chart, which will refresh the chart.